# Create small json from larger json

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have json which i have to cut into smaller jsons

```
{
    "1":"Welcome",
    "2":"Hello",
    "3":"Hi"
}
```

I have to make smaller jsons seperately:

```
{"1":"Welcome}
{"2":"Hello"}
{"3":"Hi"}
```

I read json using readjson in python and used used dict[d.items()] but it is not allowing me to slice or make division provide knowledge how to achieve this

Comment: what's your expected result, a list of JSON strings?

Comment: No Json only should be the output. Small files should also be json

Comment: Yes I do know that this is what is happening doing json.dumps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through dictionary entries and pass *dict literals* to `json.dumps`:

```
import json

d = {
    "1":"Welcome",
    "2":"Hello",
    "3":"Hi"
}
for k,v in d.items():
    print(json.dumps({k: v}))
```

The output:

```
{"1": "Welcome"}
{"2": "Hello"}
{"3": "Hi"}
```